# Django TemplateSyntax Error: Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor' - Code included

Tags: python, django, django-templates

this is my code. For some reason I'm getting Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
{% for x in x.objects.all() %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if x.left %}
        {% if x.active %}
            {% if x.round_1 %}
               {% if x.player.active %}
               {% else %}
               {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
   {% else %}
        {% if x.active %}
            {% if x.round_1 %}
               {% if x.player.active %}
               {% else %}
               {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you think `{% for x in x.objects.all() %}` is safe?

Comment: Yeah. It's not actually that, I'm passing that in through the view. It was working when there were a lot less if statements... Does the logic seem sound? Perhaps I have a rogue {% endif %}?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the view passes a model to the template. Why? Why don't you compute the queryset in the view and pass that? Try and in the model do e.g. `{% for x in all_my_objs %}`

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: The else that is least indented (in the middle)

Comment: I don't see any errors.  Can you post the real, actual template?  This is obviously just a summary.

Comment: One thing for sure there definitely shouldn't be this much of logic in a template. Some people believer there shouldn't be any logic at all inside a template.

Comment: This is super embarrassing... I was missing a closing % in one of my if statements ({% if x }